# IMobileServiceClient.PullAsync deadlock when trying to sync with Azure Mobile Services

Tags: ios, xamarin, async-await, deadlock, azure-mobile-services

I have the classes below.

```
public class AzureMobileDataContext : IAsyncInitialization
    {
        private static readonly Lazy<AzureMobileDataContext> lazy =
            new Lazy<AzureMobileDataContext> (() => 
                new AzureMobileDataContext(
                    new MobileServiceClient(
                                "http://myservice.azure-mobile.net/",
                                "123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP")));

        public static AzureMobileDataContext Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }
        public Task Initialization { get; private set; }
        public IMobileServiceClient Context { get; private set; }

        private Object lockObj = new Object ();
        private static MobileServiceSQLiteStore store;

        public AzureMobileDataContext (IMobileServiceClient context)
        {
            Context = context;
            Initialization = Init ();
            Initialization.ContinueWith (async (antecedent) => {
                await Context.SyncContext.InitializeAsync (store, new MobileServiceSyncHandler ());
            });
        }

        private Task Init ()
        {
            return Task.Run (() => {
                lock (lockObj) {
                    if (!Context.SyncContext.IsInitialized) {
                        try {
                            store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore ("mysqlite.db3");

                            store.DefineTable<Post> ();
                            store.DefineTable<PostPhotoUrl> ();
                            store.DefineTable<User> ();
                            store.DefineTable<Club> ();
                            store.DefineTable<District> ();
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            Debug.WriteLine ("Init: {0}", ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public async Task<IMobileServiceSyncTable<TEntity>> GetTableAsync<TEntity> ()
        {
            await Initialization;
            return Context.GetSyncTable<TEntity> ();
        }

        public async Task PushAsync ()
        {
            try {
                await Initialization;
                await Context.SyncContext.PushAsync ();
            } catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException invalidOperationEx) {
                Debug.WriteLine (invalidOperationEx.Message);
            } catch (MobileServicePushFailedException pushFailedException) {
                Debug.WriteLine (pushFailedException.Message);
            }
        }

        public async Task PullAsync<TEntity> (IMobileServiceTableQuery<TEntity> query)
        {
            try {
                await Initialization;
                IMobileServiceSyncTable<TEntity> entityTable = await GetTableAsync<TEntity> ();
                await entityTable.PullAsync (typeof(TEntity).ToString (), query); // Never returns, no exception is caught or thrown.
                await entityTable.PurgeAsync ();
            } catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException preconditionFailedEx) {
                Debug.WriteLine (preconditionFailedEx.Message);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Debug.WriteLine (ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public async Task SyncAsync<TEntity> ()
        {
            await PushAsync ();
            IMobileServiceSyncTable<TEntity> syncTable = await GetTableAsync<TEntity> ();
            await PullAsync (syncTable.CreateQuery ());
        }
    }
```

I use this singleton from a BaseRepository I have that is a base class for 5 different entity repositories.

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        protected AzureMobileDataContext MobileServiceContext { get { return AzureMobileDataContext.Instance; } }

        protected virtual Task PushAsync ()
        {
            return MobileServiceContext.PushAsync ();
        }

        protected virtual Task PullAsync (IMobileServiceTableQuery<TEntity> query)
        {
            return MobileServiceContext.PullAsync (query);
        }

        public virtual async Task<DataObjectResponse<IEnumerable<TEntity>>> FindAsync (Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            IMobileServiceSyncTable<TEntity> syncTable = await MobileServiceContext.GetTableAsync<TEntity> ();
            await PullAsync (syncTable.CreateQuery ());
            IEnumerable<TEntity> entities = await syncTable.Where (predicate).ToEnumerableAsync ();
            return new DataObjectResponse<IEnumerable<TEntity>> (entities);
        }
}
```

The users repository.

```
public class UsersAzureRepository : BaseRepository<User>, IUsersRepository
    {
        public UsersAzureRepository ()
        {
        }

        public async Task<DataObjectResponse<User>> FindByIdAsync (string entityId)
        {
            DataObjectResponse<IEnumerable<User>> users = await FindAsync (p => p.Id == entityId);
            return new DataObjectResponse<User>(users.Data.FirstOrDefault ());
        }
    }
```

A DataService Facade class containing the `GetUserById` method.

```
public async Task<UserModel> GetUserById (string userId)
        {
            DataObjectResponse<User> users = await UsersRepository.FindByIdAsync (userId);
            UserModel userModel = Mapper.Map<User, UserModel> (users.Data);
            return userModel;
        }
```

Users view model method.

```
public async Task<UserModel> GetUsersAsync() // testing purposes
        {
            UserModel user = await _dataService.GetUserById("032beb3b-1cbf-4a0d-809c-a25c71139c55"); 
            if (user != null) {
                Debug.WriteLine ("User loaded: {0}", user.Id);
            }
            return user;
        }
```

Call from an iOS UIViewController.

```
public async override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            UserModel user = await ViewModel.GetUsersAsync ();
        }
```

The `AzureMobileDataContext` serves more as a thread safe wrapper to the `IMobileServiceClient` context operations, making sure not multiple threads will try to initialize the database (I had an exception when using it directly to the `BaseRepository<T>` before).

I'm not so sure from here where might the problem is. I suspect that the wrapper is not the best solution and any recommendations are welcome.

Any other ways to debug the `PullAsync` method?

**[EDIT]**

The local SQLite database syncs the table data from the remote service but still the call doesn't return.

Comment: We'd like to help investigate on the Azure Mobile Services product team. Do you mind emailing mobileservices@microsoft.com so that we can try to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @lindydonna-msft of course, will do ASAP. I also want to change a little bit the architecture of the AzureMobileDataContext singleton cause it doesn't feel great, I'll move it to the DI container as a singleton and remove the lock converting it to a static method and initialize in application startup. Anyway, it seems that I got into somewhere there. I will send all the information.

Comment: @lindydonna-msft I've sent the email, thank you for the support on this. Hope we can resolve it quick :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in the Azure Mobile Service, server side.

I was returning from the TableController an IEnumerable but the SDK uses OData query expressions to do it's own job, returning an IEnumerable is not sufficient, changing to IQueryable fixed this issue of a continuous looping when pulling data.

I strongly believe that the server return type shouldn't be related to the SDK but this is the way it works.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. This is indeed confusing behavior. The reason that IQueryable behaves differently is that additional clauses can be added to it, whereas IEnumerable doesn't. However, it can be quite surprising that the return type causes such a difference in behavior!

Comment: Hi Donna, I saw today code that works fine returning IEnumerable. I want to try that architecture, I never made it to synchronize properly. I sent you code that reproduces the problem in our email discussion but I guess you missed it. I was about to crate another question when I get some time too.

Comment: I did look at your code, but I couldn't figure out the source of the problem. If you return IEnumerable, it will definitely not work the same, because the OData query options will not be applied. Those query options are necessary for offline sync to behave correctly. Otherwise, as you saw, you will end up with an infinite loop where you're getting the same results over and over again.

Comment: Yes, we fixed that, I sent you another problem :-) I'll resend to you and check it out, it was deleting the records in second pull. Anyway I'll keep you posted!