# Azure mobile services offline synchronisation

Tags: xamarin.ios, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to do some offline synchronisation from a Xamarin.iOS app. When I'm calling PullAsync on the IMobileServiceSyncTable the call never returns.

I've tried with a regular IMobileServiceTable, which seems to be working fine. The sync table seems to be the thing here that doesn't work for me

Code that doesn't work:

```
var client = new MobileServiceClient(ApiUrl);

var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore("syncstore.db");
store.DefineTable<Entity>();

await client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);
table = client.GetSyncTable<Entity>();
try
{
    await table.PullAsync("all", table.CreateQuery());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
}

return await table.ToListAsync();
```

Code that works:

```
var client = new MobileServiceClient(configuration.BaseApiUrl);
return await table.ToListAsync();
```

Can anyone point out something that seems to be wrong? I do not get any exception or nothing that points me in any direction - it just never completes.

UPDATE 1:
Seen some other SO questions where people had a similar issue because they somewhere in their call stack didn't await, but instead did a Task.Result or Task.Wait(). However, I do await this call throughout my whole chain. Here's e.g. a unit test I've written which has the exact same behaviour as described above. Hangs, and never returns.

```
[Fact]
public async Task GetAllAsync_ReturnsData()
{
    var result = await sut.GetAllAsync();
    Assert.NotNull(result);
}
```

UPDATE 2:
I've been sniffing on the request send by the unit test. It seems that it hangs, because it keeps on doing the http-request over and over several hundereds of times and never quits that operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! I've found the issue.

The problem was that the server returned an IEnumerable in the GetAll operation. Instead it should've been an IQueryable

The answer in this question pointed me in the right direction

[IMobileServiceClient.PullAsync deadlock when trying to sync with Azure Mobile Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528351/imobileserviceclient-pullasync-deadlock-when-trying-to-sync-with-azure-mobile-se)